# Is there a version of the rearrangement inequality for nonnegative functions on [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

First, let us recall the sequence version of the rearrangement inequality.

**Rearrangement inequality for nonnegative finite sequences:**  Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots\leq x_N$ and $y_1\leq y_2\leq\cdots\leq y_N$ nondecreasing sequences of nonnegative real numbers.  If $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$ then we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^Nx_{N+1-i}y_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^Nx_{\sigma(i)}y_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^Nx_iy_i.$$

(Actually, this is valid for finite real-valued sequences, not just nonnegative ones.  But I wish to restrict my attention to the nonnegative case for now.)

A rearrangement inequality for measurable nonnegative functions on $[0,1]$ may be conjectured as follows.  If $f:[0,1]\to[-\infty,\infty]$ is measurable then we define its *distribution function* $\mu_f:[0,\infty]\to[0,\infty]$ by the rule
$$\mu_f(t)=\mu\left\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>t\right\}$$
where $\mu$ is the standard Lebesgue measure.  Two functions are called *equimeasurable* of they have the same distribution function.  It is known, in particular, that $f:[0,1]\to[-\infty,\infty]$ is equimeasurable with its *nonincreasing rearrangement* $f^*:[0,1]\to[0,\infty]$ defined by
$$f^*(x)=\inf\left\{t:\mu_f(t)\leq x\right\}.$$
Hence, it is also equimeasurable with what we might call its *nondecreasing rearrangement* $f_*:[0,1]\to[0,\infty]$ defined by the rule
$$f_*(x)=f^*(1-x).$$

Observe that the rearrangement inequality for nonnegative finite sequences is equivalent to the following:  If $f:\{1,2,\cdots,N\}\to[0,\infty]$ and $g:\{1,2,\cdots,N\}\to[0,\infty]$ are measurable functions, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^Nf_*(i)g^*(i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^Nf(i)g^*(i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^Nf^*(i)g^*(i),$$
where the definitions above are extended in the obvious way to measurable functions $f,g:\{1,\cdots,N\}\to[0,\infty]$.  I conjecture the following.

**Conjecture.**  Let $f,g:[0,1]\to[0,\infty]$ be nonnegative measurable functions.  Then
$$\int_0^1f_*(x)g^*(x)\;dx\leq \int_0^1f(x)g^*(x)\;dx\leq\int_0^1f^*(x)g^*(x)\;dx.$$

The last inequality is just Hardy-Littlewood.  But I am curious if it is known whether the first inequality holds, i.e. whether
$$\int_0^1f_*(x)g^*(x)\;dx\leq \int_0^1f(x)g^*(x)\;dx.$$

Thanks!